# Listview with TextView and Checkboxes acting wierd

Tags: java, android

I have a Fragment with a ListView containing TextViews and Checkboxes. Each row of that ListView has to be clickable and when clicked, the checkbox gets checked. However, when the User selects the first row and its checkbox gets checked and then he scrolls, the last row's checkbox and some other checkboxes get also checked and that is not wanted. This is how my `getView()` Method in my Custom Adapter looks like:

**OptionsListAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final OptionRowViewHolder holder;
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        holder = new OptionRowViewHolder();
        row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mLayoutId, parent, false);
        holder.setCheckbox((CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox));
        holder.setText((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text));
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (OptionRowViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.getText().setText(mOptionsList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.getCheckbox().setTag(position);
    holder.getCheckbox().setClickable(false);

    if(mOptionsList.get(position).isSelected()){
        if((int)holder.getCheckbox().getTag() == position){
            holder.getCheckbox().setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v;
            CheckBox c = (CheckBox) layout.getChildAt(2);
            int pos = (Integer) c.getTag();
            Option option = getItem(position);
            if(c.isChecked()){
                c.setChecked(false);
                option.setSelected(false);
                mOptionsList.set(pos, option);
            }else{
                c.setChecked(true);
                option.setSelected(true);
                mOptionsList.set(pos, option);
            }
        }
    });
    return row;
}
```

This is the XML Layout for each row:

**options_list_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/option_row"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingStart="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/tv_text_size"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/text" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It is important that the whole row is clickable and not just the checkbox. I really dont know what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use holder which is checked on the 1st item of the list but not uncheck on other items when scroll. you should modify your code like this.

```
if(mOptionsList.get(position).isSelected()){
         holder.getCheckbox().setChecked(true);
 }
else
{
         holder.getCheckbox().setChecked(false);
}
```